# best way to identify sql errors while creating, updating or deleting a record in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, error-handling

I have this use case when I am saving a record after creating it and I want to check for errors, and inform my user of what happened on the sql server side without showing him the actual error message (if any occurs).

Here is what I came up with for the moment:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Book;
    use App\Http\Requests\BookRequest;
    use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;

    class BookController extends Controller {
        /* ... */

        public function store(BookRequest $request) {
            $book = new Book;

            $book->name = $request->input('name');
            $book->author = $request->input('author');
            $book->published_at = $request->input('publishDate');

            try {
                $book->save();
            }
            catch( QueryException $exception ) {
                $message = '';

                if( $exception->code == 23000 )  { // 23000: MySQL error code for "Duplicate entry"
                    $message = 'This book already exists.';
                }
                else {
                    $message = 'Could not store this book.';
                }

                return redirect()
                    ->back()
                    ->withInput()
                    ->withErrors($message);
            }

            return redirect()->route('book.index');
        }
    }
?>
```

The part where I hard code the MySQL error code bugs me and it is surely not portable.

**Question**

How are we supposed to identify database errors while saving/updating/deleting a record ?

Can we do this verification in a versatile way (database agnostic) ?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use validation before it is saved. The easiest way to achieve this would probably be using [Laravel-Model-Validation](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Model-Validation). You can do something like this:

```
class Book extends Model {
    protected static $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|unique:books',
        'published_at' => 'required|date'
    ];

    //Use this for custom messages
    protected static $messages = [
        'name.unique' => 'A book with this name already exists.'
    ];
}
```

This can easily be hand-rolled by listening for `saving`. See Jeffrey Way's [code](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Model-Validation/blob/master/src/Way/Database/Model.php#L46):

```
/**
 * Listen for save event
 */
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::saving(function($model)
    {
        return $model->validate();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Alex Harris, for the duplicate part, I would prefer to let my database trigger the error, to not have to query 2 times, one for the existance and one for the insertion. Also, for this I used my `BookRequest` in which I set up my rules like this link on [Form Request in Laravel 5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation). The question was more board as how could I anticipate a duplicate on my column a or my column b. I intended to find some api like `(new SqlError($exception))->isDuplicate()` or something like this.